# Kernel panic, real time clock (possibly), UPS Pico

Tags: kernel, rtc, crash

Have a fresh install of [KivyPie](http://kivypie.mitako.eu/), which is some months old, with updates (have done `apt update`/`upgrade`).

It crashes:

[image]

and the reason seems to be these two lines

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
```

in either `/boot/config.txt` or `/etc/modules`

I assume there is some conflict between old stuff in the OS and new updates.

**Edit**: it worked earlier, and the only difference seems to be new updates.

Does anybody know what to do about it?